# Unable to create Order from active Quote in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I am facing an error while creating an Order from Active Quote.
and also it happing only on some of the quotes records not on all.

I have done many searches and RnD related to this but I am unable to find any solution.

Below is the error, which I am getting.

```js
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">Active stage is not on 'Quote' entity.</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <OrganizationServiceFault xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <ActivityId>036f0244-f38d-4a5b-966b-6b9a4929e07a</ActivityId>
          <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
          <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
          <Message>Active stage is not on 'Quote' entity.</Message>
          <Timestamp>2017-03-15T10:59:26.7178126Z</Timestamp>
          <ExceptionSource i:nil="true"/>
          <InnerFault>
            <ActivityId>036f0244-f38d-4a5b-966b-6b9a4929e07a</ActivityId>
            <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
            <ErrorDetails xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"/>
            <Message>Active stage is not on 'Quote' entity.</Message>
            <Timestamp>2017-03-15T10:59:26.7178126Z</Timestamp>
            <ExceptionSource i:nil="true"/>
            <InnerFault i:nil="true"/>
            <OriginalException i:nil="true"/>
            <TraceText i:nil="true"/>
          </InnerFault>
          <OriginalException i:nil="true"/>
          <TraceText i:nil="true"/>
        </OrganizationServiceFault>
      </detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

My presumption is some of your quotes have been marked as won while others haven't...

You need to call `WinQuoteRequest` first before you convert it to a sales order. The order of events is this:

- WinQuoteRequest
- ConvertQuoteToSalesOrderRequest
- This Returns the Sales Order in the repsonse.Entity (ConvertQuoteToSalesOrderResponse)

This is taken from [this sample on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309346.aspx)